# Get a files name into a msg batch

Tags: file, batch-file, filenames

In my previous post i made a batch (see bellow)

```
    @ECHO OFF

XCOPY "%cd%\CTB\*.CTB" c:\ICT\AutoCAD_2010\CTB\

MSG * Hello %USERNAME%, Your CTB was successfully transferred.

exit
```

How can i achive a way to have the message display the file name (assuming that the name varries from time to time)

Answer (score 0):

If no one comes up with a more elegant solution, you can always resort to spam :-)

(inside a batch file, you need %%p from the command line %p)

```
for %%p in (%cd%\CTB\*.CTB) do MSG * Hello %USERNAME%, %%p was copied to C:\ICT\Auto...
```

For example I used:

```
C:\Users\Stephen>for %p in ("D:\My Documents\Youcam\*.jpg") do MSG * Stephen %p is here
```

to spam myself with all the avaialble graphics in that directory.

Comment: Yeah lol i need to spam some of the dumb arses i work with. some people need to be spoon fead everything that happens, "now click"now 'drag, now. yeah its a scarry world, my it managers behind me now, its thursday hes googled BMW and x-mas lights i've spent my time fixing the things he caused lol

Answer (score 0):

Since `XCOPY` displays the names of the files copied, it is possible to read the output and set an environment variable to the first line (assuming there's always one file to copy):

```
@ECHO OFF

SET filename=
FOR /F "delims=" %%R IN ('XCOPY "%cd%\CTB\*.CTB" c:\ICT\AutoCAD_2010\CTB\') DO (
  IF NOT DEFINED filename SET "filename=%%R"
)

MSG * Hello %USERNAME%, Your "%filename%" was successfully transferred.

EXIT
```